# Pass Play integrity api when app is repacked with Frida-gadget

Tags: android, frida

I have decompiled an app that uses the Play integrity API.

I attach the [Frida-gadget](https://frida.re/docs/gadget/) and rebuild/resign the apk.
After installing it on an unrooted phone (that passes the Play integrity API), the repacked app does not seems to pass it anymore (makes sense because the 'Genuine app binary' part of PI is broken).
In the Frida script I hook the following function to make it return com.android.vending

> android.app.ApplicationPackageManager.getInstallerPackageName()

But still integrity fails. Is there any known method to pass integrity?

I tried the same on a rooted phone with [Play  Integrity Fix module (magisk)](https://github.com/chiteroman/PlayIntegrityFix) installed and have gotten the same result.

Are there other function which are used to determine app integrity that I can hook?

Comment: I don't know how Play Integrity API verifies genunity of the app, but it is common security knowledge that that a system (here an app) should never try to verify itself, because if it had been tampered the verification is useless as the app could lie about it's status. So I would expect that Google implemented the check at least in Play Services or even distributed between Play Services and some backend server.

Comment: But you seem to try to modify not a regular app but Play Store app which is usually a system app working very closely e.g.with Play Services via RPC. Not sure if it is possible to do the same if the one app has been modified and uses a different APk signature.

Comment: @Robert I understand but would guess that in the end there are some data collectors of Play integrity on which the result is based that can be fooled. (In a simalar way that the Play Integrity Fix module fools the services on rooted phones to pass PI. I think that it might perhaps work when I fake the getPackageInfo.signatures result, I will try it when I find some time. The app should normally be installed from the Play Store (if not it gives a warning to do so).